# Do I need to manually segment/augment my data for transformer training?

Tags: transformer

If my dataset consists of the sentence "I have an apple" do I need to feed my model the separate examples "I" -> "have", "I have" -> "an", and "I have an" -> "apple" or is that essentially what the masking does, and I only have to feed in the entire sentence at once?

Answer (score 1):

If you are training a **decoder-only** model, you don't need any manual augmentation. Recall that a decoder-only model only allows tokens to attend to previous tokens during self-attention. Additionally, decoder-only models will often predict the next token at the position of the next-to-last token. In other words, the model's output representation at position $i$ (say, $h_i$) is used to predict the token $t_{i+1}$, with $h_i$ only depending on tokens $t_1, ..., t_{i-1}$.

So, with a single forward pass, **each** output hidden state $h_i$ (and subsequent token prediction) constitutes a valid autoregressive prediction (i.e., it predicts the next token based on only the previous values).

Contrast that with training an **encoder-only** MLM model, like [BERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805), where (part of) the pretraining objective is to predict a masked-out word. This masking can be in the form of a `[MASK]` token or a randomly chosen token. You have to do *some* kind of masking as otherwise the model will just learn to repeat the input token (although in the BERT paper, they do leave the token unchanged 10% of the time). To produce these masks, you need to do some preprocessing beforehand, although you can mask multiple tokens (and thus calculate losses for them) in a single forward pass.

**Encoder-decoder models** are often also trained a similar way. E.g., for [T5](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.10683), you mask out, then predict consecutive spans of tokens, but your model can predict multiple token spans per forward pass.